# ReactJS if prop exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

at the moment I am getting an error with React because I am mapping an array of objects from a REST end point and some of the objects in the array don't have certain props.

An example is that some of my objects have another object within them called `images`and some don't. When my React component tries to render the objects without the `images` I am left with an error undefined prop.

Here is my component that renders my prop:

```
const VehicleDetail = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={"col-flex-md-3 col-flex-sm-4 col-flex-xs-6 col-flex-media-query vehicle-item " + props.vehicle.brand.name} data-value={props.vehicle.brand.name}>
      <div className="vehicle-container">
        <img src={"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pulman-vw-images/uploads/images/thumbnails/" + props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name} />
        <h4 className="vehicle-title">
          {props.vehicle.model.name}
        </h4>
        <div className="row-flex">
          <div className="col-flex-xs-12 btn-container">
            <a href={"http://beaver" + props.vehicle.brand.name + ".co.uk/new/cars/" + props.vehicle.slug} target="_blank" className="learn-more-btn">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So as you can see I have an `img` element with a prop of `props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name` however this fails as some of my objects don't have this object available.

So far I have tried adding an inline conditional just to see if the object existed first however this failed with an error:

```
<img src={"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pulman-vw-images/uploads/images/thumbnails/" + {if (typeof props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name == "object") { props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name }}} />
```

Here is my component that iterates over each object and renders them to my VehicleDetail component:

```
// Vehicle List Component
import VehicleDetail from './vehicle-detail.js';

// Create our component
const VehicleList = (props) => {
  // Just add props.vehicle to access API data instead of static
  const RenderedVehicles = props.vehicles.map(vehicle =>
    <VehicleDetail key={vehicle.slug} vehicle={vehicle} />
  );

  return (
    <div className="row-flex center-xs">
      {RenderedVehicles}
      {console.log(props.brandSelect)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any idea what the best practice in React JS is to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check the length of offers before rendering.

```
{props.vehicle.offers.length > 0 ? (
  <img src={url + props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name} />
) : null}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this. In your vehicle component declare a variable that would hold the thumbnail url.

```
const VehicleDetail = (props) => {
  let vehicleThumbnail = '';

  if (props.vehicle.offers[0].image && props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name) {
     vehicleThumbnail = props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name;
  }


  return (
    <div className={"col-flex-md-3 col-flex-sm-4 col-flex-xs-6 col-flex-media-query vehicle-item " + props.vehicle.brand.name} data-value={props.vehicle.brand.name}>
      <div className="vehicle-container">
        <img src={vehicleThumbnail} />
        <h4 className="vehicle-title">
          {props.vehicle.model.name}
        </h4>
        <div className="row-flex">
          <div className="col-flex-xs-12 btn-container">
            <a href={"http://beaver" + props.vehicle.brand.name + ".co.uk/new/cars/" + props.vehicle.slug} target="_blank" className="learn-more-btn">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'd also do the same for the other props.

Answer (score 1):

The normal case of `props.vehicle.offers[0]` may looks like this:

```
{
  image: {
    name: 'hello'
  }
}
```

So, you can use `props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name` without any error.

But some cases are:

```
{
  anotherProperty: {

  }
}
```

`props.vehicle.offers[0].image` is `null`, so `props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name` equals to `null.name`, which throw the error.

A simple way to solve the problem is something like this:

```
{ props.vehicle.offers[0].image && <img src={"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pulman-vw-images/uploads/images/thumbnails/" + props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name} /> }
```

If `props.vehicle.offers[0].image` is `null`, the statement after `&&` will not be execute, and return nothing to render.

So, it render `img` element when `props.vehicle.offers[0].image` is not null, preventing the error.